# single backend Language or different frontend Language in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, backend

is it possible to change the language of my wordpress installation (WP 3.0 Multisite) only in frontend (without editing the .mo/.po files)?

changing this option here:
[image: lang]

does also change my language in backend.

any ideas?

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

all this plugins didn't effect as i wanted, so i created my own plugin.

available here:
[one-backend-language](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/one-backend-language) (working with 3.0)

> Lets you choose your Backend Language for your complete Backend, also if your Frontend is using another Language (including Multisite).
>   You can choose from any language you installed. For a list of availible languages, check ["WordPress_in_Your_Language"](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language) or create your own files.

Answer (score 2):

i'm looking for this information too.
for now i have found this links useful: 
wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bogo/ 
wordpress.org/extend/plugins/admin-in-english/

oh, finaly. this plugsin solves my problem:
Kau-Boy's Backend Localization
just install it trough the Plugin Manager
or from here:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kau-boys-backend-localization/
and then default wordpress language - will be in the front-end
back-end language you can set in plugin settings.
p.s. for full multi-language support you can use wpml.org

regards,
DimeDroll